# Web Service Automation using Java

Tags: java, web-services, automation

I'm trying to automate a web service application using java. What i'm looking here is to send a SOAP message by reading it from a file and checking the values in the response returned from the web service.

Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want to automate *testing* a web service.

Have a look at [SOAP UI](http://www.soapui.org/).